# is it possible mysql make column title like this?

Tags: mysql

```
---------------------
|      student      |
---------------------
|  name    |  age   |
---------------------
|  John    |   17   |
|  Tony    |   18   |
```

So i want column title contains student, name and age like position i have in above.

Is it possible by mysql? How?

Comment: Tell us what you tried, show us some SQL, and we might actually bother thining about helping you.

Comment: You will need two selects...one select for just the student string, and the next select for the data with columns, The formatting can be handled as per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/selecting-columns.html

Comment: i think mysql is not place where you should do thinks like this (i think it's not even posable to do this)... you have php (or whatever you use) where you can do think like this very easy...

Comment: You do that in your presentation software. MySQL is a database. Use the proper tool for the job. MySQL stores and manipulates data. Use other software to display it (your web pages, a report engine, a user interface in an application, etc). SQL is not designed for presentation; you shouldn't try to use it for that purpose.

Comment: Somewhat like this? seems JSON can be used, I think.

row 1: {"name" : "john", "age" : "17"}  
row 2: {"name" : "tony", "age" : "18"}

Answer (score 0):

Well...actually you can do this with MySQL but as Aleksandar mentioned, you will have better control using your server side scripting/programming language like PHP, C#/.NET, Python etc.

**Example Table**

```
create table test (
  firstname varchar(15),
  lastname varchar(15)
);
```

**Stored Routine/Procedure**

Although tedious to manually adjust spaces, testing, adjusting spacing again, testing etc., you will notice that MySQL can do some formatting work.

```
delimiter $$

drop procedure if exists test_print$$

create procedure test_print()
begin
    select '-----------------------------';
    select '          Students           ';
    select '-----------------------------';
    select '  First name      Last name  ';
    select '-----------------------------';
    select
        concat(
            lpad(rpad(firstname, 15, '.'), 17, '.'),
            ' ', lastname)
        from test;
end$$

delimiter ;
```

**Execute from command line**

`-N` switch ignores column heading. `-B` does batch processing. `-e` asks MySQL to execute the query in single quotation.

```
mysql -N -B -u username -p -e 'use schemaname; call test_print();'
```

**Result**

```
-----------------------------
          Students
-----------------------------
  First name      Last name
-----------------------------
  John            Smith
  Matthew         Goldberg
```

As you may notice, although possible in MySQL, other tools may be better at reporting and formatting than MySQL.